# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.app.users.getEmail()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

few hours ago i added more tables in my firebase database. After that the app is crashing while reading the value
the value is fetched fine from Firebase but the app is crashing here

please find the logs and Screenshot of Database below

```
2020-01-21 20:44:44.652 1499-1499/com.example.app D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-01-21 20:44:44.654 1499-1499/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 1499
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.app.users.getEmail()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.app.AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.showData(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.java:232)
        at com.example.app.AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.access$000(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.java:41)
        at com.example.app.AndroidDashboardDesignActivity$1.onDataChange(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.java:135)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7055)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:536)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
2020-01-21 20:44:44.686 1499-1499/com.sdgi.sdcmt I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1499 SIG: 9
```

Please check the screenshot for firebase database
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zup3O.png)

[image]

Code at at

```
com.sdgi.sdcmt.AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.showData(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.java:232)

//            uinfo.setFullname(ds.child(userID).getValue(users.class).getFullname());//set Name
            uinfo.setEmail(ds.child(userID).getValue(users.class).getEmail());//set Email
//            uinfo.setEmail(ds.child(userID).getValue(users.class).getEmail());//set Email
//


(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.java:41)

public class AndroidDashboardDesignActivity extends Activity implements UpdateHelper.OnUpdateCheckListener {
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidDashboardActivity";


(AndroidDashboardDesignActivity.java:135)


        myref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                showData(dataSnapshot);
            }
```

i added

```
Log.d(TAG, "datashot:  " + ds.toString());
```

in my code. which is showing data is properly fetching -

`2020-01-21 20:44:44.650 1499-1499/com.example.app D/AndroidDashboardActivity: datashot:  DataSnapshot { key = 3YXBv4pE42gVMWuR0XXXXXXXXXXXX, value = {zipcode=123456, country=mycountry, newuser=no, password=12345678, address=myaddress, gender=Male, city=mycity, mobile=1234567890, rollno=1234567890, fullname=ahjsjsj, email=mail2@mail.com} }`

Comment: The issue is with the code, please provide the code at the error line.

Comment: As the error says, `com.example.app.users` is null. I'd suggest using standard naming for classes, which is a class with a capital letter, so that should likely be `com.example.app.Users`, but it seems more likely that you're talking about a _single_ user, not multiple.

Comment: Yes, but the naming is not doing anything wrong here, before adding tables in firebase it was working fine, but I will try renaming the class, Thanks for quick response

Comment: `ds.child(userID).getValue(users.class)` is returning null, which means there is no data at the location in the database you're querying.

Comment: Use debug tools (break points) for your IDE to debug actual values of the line in question (232). My guess is you are passing a null `users` object to `getValue()` which in turn returns a null `users` reference, and you are invoking a method (`getEmail()`) on the null reference.

Comment: i added Log.d(TAG, "datashot:  " + ds.toString()); which is showing data is properly fetching - 
2020-01-21 20:44:44.650 1499-1499/com.example.app D/AndroidDashboardActivity: datashot:  DataSnapshot { key = 3YXBv4pE42gVMWuR0XXXXXXXXXXXX, value = {zipcode=123456, country=mycountry, newuser=no, password=12345678, address=myaddress, gender=Male, city=mycity, mobile=1234567890, rollno=1234567890, fullname=ahjsjsj, email=mail2@mail.com} }